# @ControllerAdvice exception handler method are not get called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following controller class

```
package com.java.rest.controllers;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private VoucherService voucherService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/redeemedVoucher", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity redeemedVoucher(@RequestParam("voucherCode") String voucherCode) throws Exception {
    if(voucherCode.equals( "" )){
        throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(null, null);
    }
    Voucher voucher=voucherService.findVoucherByVoucherCode( voucherCode );
    if(voucher!= null){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        voucher.setStatus( "redeemed" );
        voucher.setAmount(new BigDecimal(0));
        voucherService.redeemedVoucher(voucher);
        return new ResponseEntity(voucher, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
    else{
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
};
```

}

And for exception handling I am using Spring3.2 advice handler as follow

```
package com.java.rest.controllers;


@ControllerAdvice
public class VMSCenteralExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

@ExceptionHandler({
    MethodArgumentNotValidException.class
})
public ResponseEntity<String> handleValidationException( MethodArgumentNotValidException methodArgumentNotValidException ) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK );
}

 @ExceptionHandler({ClassNotFoundException.class})
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(ClassNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
            String bodyOfResponse = "This Voucher is not found";
            return handleExceptionInternal(null, bodyOfResponse,
              new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND , request);
        }
```

}

I have defined XML bean definition as

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.rest" />
```

Exception thrown from controller are not handled by controller advice handler. I have googled for hours but could not find any reference why it is happening.
I followed as described http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/ here.

If anybody knows about please let know why handler is not handling exception.

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution for the above problem. Actually @ControllerAdvice needs MVC namespace declaration in XML file. Or we can use @EnableWebMvc with @ControllerAdvice annotation.

Comment: To further clarity this answer, the subclass of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler must be included in the path of @ComponentScan in order for Spring container to detect it.  I don't think the documentation is very clear on this.  Hope this save some people some time.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "needs MVC namespace declaration"?

Comment: @EricB. By MVC namespace declaration I mean, we should have <mvc:annotation-driven/> in our configuration xml file (eg. applicationConfig.xml). If we are not using <mvc:annotation-driven/> in xml file then we have to use EnableWebMvc with ControllerAdvice annotation.

Comment: @VishalSingh I am facing same problem in mu\y application.@ControllerAdvice exception handler method are not get called.I have tried with the given solution but still the problem is there.Can you please help me to get out of it

Comment: @rachana, please check if your controller advice bean is in your scan path. And also check your spring version.@ControllerAdvice annotation is available for spring3.2 or greater.

Comment: @VishalSingh I have check the all you just mention but still at same place.

Comment: @rachana, can you please share code snippet related to your controller advice

Comment: @VishalSingh see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698063/controlleradvice-exception-handler-method-not-get-called) Question i have posted

Comment: @VishalSingh upvote for question as am facing same issue and stuck with it

Comment: This explanation is wrong@EnableWebMvc has no influence to @ControllerAdvice.

Comment: In my case handler annotated by @ControllerAdvice does not catch absent requried http header exception.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem.

Managed to fix it in September 2017.

My case was that the Exception handler was in its own com.example.Exceptions package, and the problem was it was not scanned by Spring ComponentScan.

Solution is to add it in the ComponentScan like so:

```
@ComponentScan({ "x.y.z.services", "x.y.z.controllers", "x.y.z.exceptions" })
```

Comment: And if it's a Spring Boot application, you can use @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"x.y.z.services", "x.y.z.controllers", "x.y.z.exceptions"})

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VMSCenteralExceptionHandler implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

and add your bean into your config.xml

```
<bean class="com.java.rest.controllers.VMSCenteralExceptionHandler " />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform these 2 steps :

1. Add **@ControllerAdvice** on top of the global exception handler class.
2. Add your package name of exception class in component-scan i.e.

   > `<context:component-scan
   >   base-package="com.hr.controller,com.hr.exceptions" />`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is probably that your controller method throws `Exception` but your `@ControllerAdvice` methods catch specific exceptions. Either combine them into one handler that catches `Exception`, or make your controller throw those specific exceptions.

So your controller method signature should be:

```
public ResponseEntity redeemedVoucher(@RequestParam("voucherCode") String voucherCode) throws MethodArgumentNotValidException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

OR your controller advice should only have one method with the annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler({
    Exception.class
})
```