# @ControllerAdvice exception handler method not get called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, controller

I am working on sample demo application for Exception Handling in Spring MVC.I am trying `Exception Handling With @ControllerAdvice`

I followed steps as describe in [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/) link.

But when i run my application i get the following error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.test.core.ApplicationException
```

For more details following are the classes I am working on

**ApplicationException.java**

```
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -9061684361606685158L;
private ErrorStatus errorStatus;
private int msgNumber;
private Object []args;

public ApplicationException(){}

public ApplicationException(ErrorStatus errorStatus, int msgNumber,
        Object[] args) {
    this.errorStatus = errorStatus;
    this.msgNumber = msgNumber;
    this.args = args;
  }
    //getter setters
}
```

Controller class

**ApplicationExceptionController.java**

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/exception")
public class ApplicationExceptionController {

@RequestMapping(value="/error",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void helloException() 
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ErrorStatus.NotFound,1,new Object[]{"Website"});

  //here ErrorStatus is a enum class
}  
}
```

And here is the GlobalExceptionHandler class

**GlobalExceptionHandler.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler
public void notFount(){
    System.out.println("----------CaughtApplicationException-----------");
}
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"      
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 

xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan  base-package="com.test.controller,com.test.core" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />   
</bean>  

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
     <list> <ref bean="jsonConverter"/></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
     <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

I run above application with       http://localhost:8080/SpringExceptionHandling/exception/error this url

But I get the following Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.test.core.ApplicationException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

com.test.core.ApplicationException
com.test.controller.ApplicationExceptionController.helloException(ApplicationExceptionController.java:19)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I go through [@ControllerAdvice exception handler method are not get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582411/controlleradvice-exception-handler-method-are-not-get-called#) this link but still stuck with the same problem
Please help me to get the solution.I am not getting the actual cause for this exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in your Exception handler. Your Exception handler should be like this.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ApplicationException.class})
    public void notFount(){
        System.out.println("----------CaughtApplicationException-----------");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public void notFountGlobal(){
        System.out.println("----------CaughtApplicationException-----------");
    }

}
```

Also you need to tell exception handler method which exception you want to catch in which method. At last you can specify a method which can caught all other exception passing it Exception.class.
The code snippet you post work for me. Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Still not working.Is this code is working on your side?If yes can you please share the jars names you are using,I think am missing some jar file

Comment: @rachana, spring-core, spring-web, spring-webmvc. Are you using maven project?

Comment: no ,am not using maven project.I have all these jars in my project of version 4.0.0

Comment: @rachana, can you upload your demo project on git and share the URL of repo?

Comment: @rachana,, this works for me, Git is down right, I will upload my code and let you know.

Comment: I have uploaded my project but now git is down. please let me know when you upload your project and please upload jars also if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77143/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-rachana).

Comment: `@EnableWebMvc` is a `@Configuration` annotation and does not alter the behavior of a `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: If you're creating a Spring *Boot* application, you should not use `@EnableWebMvc`: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the handler method is not called because of additional parameter in the method signature.

**Not working:**

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handle404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e,  @RequestHeader(value = "referer", required = false) final String referer) {
    ...
}
```

The `referer` parameter is what caused the handler method not being called. The problem is solved after removing the parameter.

**Works:**

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handle404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declared the exception so that the method can be mapped to the exception type. You have two possibilities, either state the exception as an argument

```
public void notFount(ApplicationException exception){
```

**or**

add the type as a value attribute of your @ExceptionHandler annotation

```
 @ExceptionHandler(value = ApplicationException.class)
```

In addition, you most likely have a config issue, 'cause with the erroneus `GlobalExceptionHandler` that you've posted, the servlet wouldn't start-up, explicitly saying that no exception types are mapped to the method. Make sure that you're scanning the package where your `GlobalExceptionHandler` resides, by the looks of things, that is most likely your issue

Comment: I have tried it but still am getting the same exception.The controller not get invoke

Comment: Map your exception to a method in the way I've mentioned in the answer, and make sure that you scan the `com.test.core` package, the rest seems fine, let me know if works for you

Comment: As you suggested I checked my config and I have already added `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`  element in my config and also have added `com.test.core` package.I have Updated my question please have a look.

Comment: I would expect that with the change config it works, pls change the `GlobalExceptionHandler` as well, re-test, and paste the logs. We the updated global exception handler config and codewise you should be fine

Comment: Revisited the question, in fact the packate to scan should be wherever is your `GlobalExceptionHandler` so not the `com.test.core` which I falsly assumed when reading the exception stacktrace, rather the package of your `GlobalExceptionHandler` class whichever it is

Comment: +1 for help.My problem get solve but in spring 3.2.0 version & am using 4.0.0 version of spring and there is still same issue.