# Spring boot rest API @Valid @ExceptionHandler only working inside RestController

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I would like to validate the entity at controller level for Spring rest api.
Here is my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orgs")
public class OrganizationController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> addOrganization(@Valid @RequestBody Organization organization){
        //code here
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> invalidInput(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {        
        ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
        response.setSuccess(false);
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

If I include ExceptionHandler within my controller class it is working fine. But if I move this exceptionHandler inside the @ControllerAdvice like below its NOT working.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> invalidInput(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
        response.setSuccess(false);
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

From the console logs I found that it was scanned:

```
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in defaultExceptionHandler
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionHandlingController
```

But ExceptionHandler methods is NOT getting called.

Am I did anything wrong ?

Comment: Did you run into the similar problem like this post [@ControllerAdvice exception handler method are not get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582411/controlleradvice-exception-handler-method-are-not-get-called#)?

Comment: @LHCHIN I tried with EnableWebMvc also but no luck. Without adding EnableWebMvc also ExceptionHandler is detected by spring component scan. but method is not getting called. I am not getting what is the issue !!! :(

Answer (score 0):

try to use `@ExceptionHandler(value = BindException.class)`

Answer (score 0):

As it's been mentioned in [`Spring Docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html#annotations--):

> Controllers that are annotated with this/one of those annotation(s) will be assisted by the @ControllerAdvice annotated class.

Try to set `annotations` element of `ControllerAdvice` annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
```